# Android Studio on Dual Xeon Workstation

Tags: performance, android-studio, cpu

Curious if anyone out there is doing Android Studio development on a dual Xeon machine.

I would like to know if the additional CPU gave a dramatic or visible (50% or more) boost in build performance.

Comment: Happened to come across a dual socket LGA1366 Dell workstation that I got off ebay for about a $100. It came with 2 Quad core xeons, I will be replacing them with 2 x 6 Core X5650s (12 Cores, 24 Threads). My main dev machine is a single x5650, so I should be able to get a good comparison on build performance. Will post numbers soon.

Comment: How did that go in the end? Wanting to move to a dual Xeon setup - if not numbers, any info will help!

Answer (score 3):

You probably found out, but for others wondering: Chances are - it won't.

Did some testing with two relatively quick E2650 v4 Xeons on a largish Java + Kotlin project and Xeons were considerably slower than low core count / higher clock CPU's.

Check out the benchmarks here:
https://superuser.com/questions/1115206/will-dual-xeons-improve-android-studio-build-times/

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to measure speed of Android Studio 3.1.4 on the same hardware: Macbook Pro 2011, RAM 4Gb, SSD 240GB Samsung, Core i5 2.4Ghz.
I have installed on this machine 3 different OS: Windows 10, MacOS Hight Sierra 10.13, Ubuntu 18.04.
Avarage build time (running command: gradlew clean build, gradlew clean assembleRelease) on MacOS/Ubuntu was around 30% faster than on Windows.

On my another working machine: Core i5 3.0 Ghz 7400, RAM 16Gb, SSD 250Gb. Build time takes 4.34min on Windows 10 machine. 
The same project on a little bit slower processor, but with the same RAM and SSD and it is running Ubuntu 16.04 build time takes two times faster!! 
Well I was shocked with results, but still I choose Windows as development machine, because it's much more comfortable for me to use comfortable and 
usable keyboard and sotfware than on Unix like systems. And even if I had to choose between MacOS and Ubuntu - mac is really much easier to setup everything, and 
Ubuntu is too complex to use for usual people. Choise is up to you.

Comment: That's probably because of Windows Defender. On Windows disable Windows Defender and any other antivirus/anti malware you run. You should see build times improve by a lot. After that you can add exclusion folders to exclude any folders Android Studio uses from Windows Defender real time scans.

Comment: Just to clarify, I did not mean to test/scan your system for viruses. Windows Defender scans in memory & on disc items that are in current use, as such it interferes with builds. Its true for Android Studio, Visual Studio and any other dev IDE.